# Struggling to properly format strings

Tags: java, string, api, format

```
for(Item i : itemArray){
System.out.format("%1s%50s%50s", "name = " + i.getName(), "color = " + i.getColor(), "quantity = " + i.getQuantity());
System.out.println();
```

I am attempting to iterate over an item array, printing out each item in a formatted table. 
Each item had a name, color, quantity and price.

Here is how it currently comes out as:

```
Name: bike       Color: black       Quantity: 1      Price: 6.00
Name: ladder       Color: blue       Quantity: 150      Price: 9.00
Name: dolphin       Color: orange       Quantity: 15      Price: 100000.00
Name: key       Color: red       Quantity: 12      Price: 510.00
```

Here is what I need it to look like:

```
Name: bike       Color: black      Quantity: 1       Price: 6.00
Name: ladder     Color: blue       Quantity: 150     Price: 9.00
Name: dolphin    Color: orange     Quantity: 15      Price: 100000.00
Name: key        Color: red        Quantity: 12      Price: 510.00
```

I have read the format api and still can not figure it out!!! please help.

Answer (score 4):

Your format string should specify more than a single character width (`%1s`) for the Name: param:

```
System.out.format("%15s%50s%50s", "name = " + i.getName(), "color = " + i.getColor(), "quantity = " + i.getQuantity());
```

More readable would be to only inject your variables into the format string:

```
System.out.format("Name: %-10s  Color: %-10s Quantity: %-10s Price: %s", ...)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try as

```
        String fmt = "Name: %-10s Color: %-10s Quantity: %d%n";
        System.out.printf(fmt, "bike", "black", 1);
        System.out.printf(fmt, "ladder", "blue", 1);
```

output

```
Name: bike       Color: black      Quantity: 1
Name: ladder     Color: blue       Quantity: 1
```